# Angular 9 liveload throws Javascript Heap error

Tags: angular, docker

I have upgraded Angular 9 and it's working fine on development but if I modify any code, ng serve liveload throws the JavaScript heap out of memory. I have increased the old space size to 4096

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

but still the same error. I am not sure, why ng serve works fine but subsequent liveload throws an error. Here are the exceptions

<--- Last few GCs --->

[37:0x45d83c0] 10739196 ms: Mark-sweep 1999.6 (2080.0) -> 1984.8 (2081.5) MB, 1372.6 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.164, current mu = 0.074) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[37:0x45d83c0] 10740508 ms: Mark-sweep 2001.0 (2081.5) -> 1986.8 (2083.8) MB, 1215.7 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.124, current mu = 0.073) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 0xa04200 node::Abort() [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
2: 0x94e4e9 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
3: 0xb7860e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
4: 0xb78987 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
5: 0xd33215  [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
6: 0xd33d9f  [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
7: 0xd41e2b v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
8: 0xd459ec v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
9: 0xd140cb v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
10: 0x105a06f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
11: 0x1400039  [ng serve --poll=2000 --source-map=false --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4300]
Aborted

Can anyone face the same issue? or know the solution on it?

Answer (score 0):

updating my answer to the most likely solution
project size likely exceeds vmemory at 4096 MB
try changing it to 8192 MB and it should work
I typically run into this when working with ELK stack.

Comment: I am getting javascript heap out of memory and as per my knowledge liveload internally by angular in ng serve using watcher so not sure how to use npm install

Comment: Are you working on a large project? If so, try doubling the virtual mem cap to 4096 * 2 = 8192 and try serving it

Comment: ng node --max_old_space_size=8192 && ng build